# Caption of Figure and legend under the figure

Tags: pgfplots

I want to give under the graph  legends and \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.}. Delete  line papralel x axis

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % f1
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        xlabel=Time,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        legend pos=south west]
    \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 9\\
            4 9.1\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 9.8\\
            24 9.162\\
            48 9\\
            72 9.1\\
            168 9.8\\};
             \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 9.2\\
            4 8.1\\
            8 8.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 9.62\\
            48 9.3\\
            72 9.1\\
            168 8.8\\};
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 8.7\\
            4 9.2\\
            8 8.9\\
            12 9.6\\
            24 9.2\\
            48 8\\
            72 8.1\\
            168 8.8\\};
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 7\\
           4 7.1\\
           8 7.8\\
           12 7.8\\
           24 7.162\\
           48 7.6\\
           72 7.1\\
           168 7.8\\};
    \label{plot_one}
    \addlegendentry{plot 1}
    \end{axis}
    % f2
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        hide x axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={Relative Expression},
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=6,
        legend pos=south west]
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}\addlegendentry{plot 4} 
    \addplot [black, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 1.3\\
4 1.8\\
8 1.4\\
12 1.3\\
24 1.85\\
48 1.48\\
72 1.63\\
168 1.75\\};
             \addplot [black, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 1.6\\
4 3.8\\
8 2.4\\
12 1.3\\
24 2.85\\
48 1.48\\
72 2.63\\
168 3.75\\};
            \addplot [black, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 0.3\\
4 0.8\\
8 0.4\\
12 0.3\\
24 0.85\\
48 0.48\\
72 0.63\\
168 0.75\\};
            \addplot [black, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 0.8\\
4 1.2\\
8 1.24\\
12 2.3\\
24 2.85\\
48 2.48\\
72 2.63\\
168 2.75\\};
    \addlegendentry{plot 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding your question... can you please try to clarify it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `caption` you need to put the diagram in `figure` environment. To see it in `preview`, the option `floats` should be added. For legend outside of diagram `pgfplot` assume only option `outer north east`, so for the legend below you need to change legend style.

I not figured out what you like to put in legend, so I left legend for `f1` as you provided in MWE in redesign it for `f2` as I supposed the legend should be. My changes in your MWE are denoted with `% <----`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{caption} % <----
    \captionsetup{font = small} % <----

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% <---
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{figure} % <---
    \centering % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%% f1
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        xlabel=Time,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={log(Cfu/cm$^{2}$)},
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        legend style={at={(0.48,-0.15)},  % <---
                      anchor=north east}] % <---
    \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 9\\
            4 9.1\\
            8 9.8\\
            12 9.8\\
            24 9.162\\
            48 9\\
            72 9.1\\
            168 9.8\\};
             \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 9.2\\
            4 8.1\\
            8 8.8\\
            12 8.8\\
            24 9.62\\
            48 9.3\\
            72 9.1\\
            168 8.8\\};
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 8.7\\
            4 9.2\\
            8 8.9\\
            12 9.6\\
            24 9.2\\
            48 8\\
            72 8.1\\
            168 8.8\\};
            \addplot [black, fill=white, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
           0 7\\
           4 7.1\\
           8 7.8\\
           12 7.8\\
           24 7.162\\
           48 7.6\\
           72 7.1\\
           168 7.8\\};
    \label{plot_one}
    \addlegendentry{plot 1}
    \end{axis}
%%%% f2
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis,
        hide x axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=168,
        ylabel={Relative Expression},
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=6,
        legend columns=2,                % <---
        legend style={at={(0.52,-0.15)}, % <---
                      anchor=north west}]% <---
]
%    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
    \addplot [black, mark=square*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 1.3\\
4 1.8\\
8 1.4\\
12 1.3\\
24 1.85\\
48 1.48\\
72 1.63\\
168 1.75\\};
    \addlegendentry{plot 1} % <---
             \addplot [black, mark=*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 1.6\\
4 3.8\\
8 2.4\\
12 1.3\\
24 2.85\\
48 1.48\\
72 2.63\\
168 3.75\\};
    \addlegendentry{plot 2} % <---
            \addplot [black, mark=diamond*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
            0 0.3\\
4 0.8\\
8 0.4\\
12 0.3\\
24 0.85\\
48 0.48\\
72 0.63\\
168 0.75\\};
    \addlegendentry{plot 3} % <---
            \addplot [black, mark=triangle*]
        table[row sep=crcr]{
0 0.8\\
4 1.2\\
8 1.24\\
12 2.3\\
24 2.85\\
48 2.48\\
72 2.63\\
168 2.75\\};
    \label{plot_four}
    \addlegendentry{plot 4} % <---
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Growth of different types foodborne pathogens.} % <---
    \end{figure} % <---
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thak you very much Zarko, also how can I to delete line above/up to major X axis. I dont want line which conect number 10 and 6, two Y axis